# What does \ means in programming?

Tags: vba, operators, backslash

I am using the following algorithm to convert a temperature to an RGB colour. Does any one knows what that slash `\` at the the second line means?

```vbs
Set Temperature = Temperature \ 100
```

What is that?

> Start with a temperature, in Kelvin, somewhere between 1000 and 40000.  (Other values may work,

```vbs
Set Temperature = Temperature \ 100

Calculate Red:

If Temperature <= 66 Then
    Red = 255
Else
    Red = Temperature - 60
    Red = 329.698727446 * (Red ^ -0.1332047592)
    If Red < 0 Then Red = 0
    If Red > 255 Then Red = 255
End If

Calculate Green:

If Temperature <= 66 Then
    Green = Temperature
    Green = 99.4708025861 * Ln(Green) - 161.1195681661
    If Green < 0 Then Green = 0
    If Green > 255 Then Green = 255
Else
    Green = Temperature - 60
    Green = 288.1221695283 * (Green ^ -0.0755148492)
    If Green < 0 Then Green = 0
    If Green > 255 Then Green = 255
End If

Calculate Blue:

If Temperature >= 66 Then
    Blue = 255
Else

    If Temperature <= 19 Then
        Blue = 0
    Else
        Blue = Temperature - 10
        Blue = 138.5177312231 * Ln(Blue) - 305.0447927307
        If Blue < 0 Then Blue = 0
        If Blue > 255 Then Blue = 255
    End If

End If
```

Comment: It means integer division, giving an integer result, as distinct from floating-point division that gives a floating-point result.

Comment: Why the rgb tag here? It's completely irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 0):

For pseudocode, a `\` normally means division, and a `*` (instead of `x`) normally means multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what "language" the pseudocode is referring to. As noted in a comment it could mean integer division (if you're working with standard imperative languages) or it could mean the reverse of the operations (`b\a == a/b`) in languages like Octave and Matlab.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)

Comment: Upvote for noting that isnt the typical division sign and could have other meanings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) with the use of `End If`, `Set`, `^` for power...

In VB `\` is an [integer division operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/integer-division-operator) so `Temperature \ 100` means taking the integer part of the result `Temperature / 100`

> In Visual BASIC (and some other BASIC dialects) the backslash is used as an operator symbol to indicate integer division. This rounds toward zero.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash#Programming_languages